# How do I pass AngularFirestoreCollection of a custom type to BehaviorSubject?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I'm writing an angular application that uses firebase/firestore for backend data. I have a custom type called "Product" which has several properties. In my ProductService I have the CRUD operations. The app will be having dialog components for edit and delete so i'm using a BehaviorSubject in the service. What i'm getting stuck on is that when I pass the collection of Products in the BehaviorSubject it doesn't recognize the type.

See my code below. In the getAll() method is where my issue is. When I apss productsRef to the next method of the BehaviorSubject (products$) the IDE has an error:

> Argument of type 'AngularFirestoreCollection' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Product[]'.

Im missing something, any ideas?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Product } from '../models/product.model';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {
  private userId: string;
  products$: BehaviorSubject<Product[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  productsRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AuthService, private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.afAuth.getCurrentUser().then(u => {
      this.userId = u.uid;
      this.products$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
      this.productsRef = db.collection('products').doc(this.userId).collection('items');         
    });
  }

  getAll(): AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>{
    if(!this.userId) return;
    this.products$.next(this.productsRef);
  }

  create(product: Product): any {
    return this.productsRef.add({...product});
  }

  update(id: string, data: any): Promise<void>{
    return this.productsRef.doc(id).update(data);
  }

  delete(id: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.productsRef.doc(id).delete();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Array<Product>` is not the same type as `AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>`. I'm not very experienced with Angular Firestore, but the basic demo looks to utilize the observable returned from `AngularFirestoreCollection.valueChanges()`. Therefore, you code could look like the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Product } from '../models/product.model';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {
  private userId: string;
  products$: Observable<Product[]>;
  productsRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AuthService, private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.afAuth.getCurrentUser().then(u => {
    this.userId = u.uid;
    this.productsRef = db.collection('products').doc(this.userId).collection('items');         
    this.products$ = this.productsRef.valueChanges();
    });
  }

  create(product: Product) {
    return this.productsRef.add({...product});
  }

  update(id: string, data: any){
    return this.productsRef.doc(id).update(data);
  }
}
```

Then in your component, you don't need to invoke `getAll()` from this service. You can simply subscribe to `products$` and receive new updates as products are added/removed.

Comment: I went by the pattern here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5290817/Build-Angular-data-table-with-CRUD-operations-and - see the person.service under implement crud operations. I wonder why they didn't simplify it the way you described?